# Why can I release an ivar after [super dealloc] without segfaulting?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, memory-management, dealloc

It seems that in Objective-C, the method that is responsibile for memory allocation (like `malloc()` in C), is `-[NSObject alloc]`. What about freeing that memory? Is that done by `-[NSObject dealloc]`? Is that why in our own class's `dealloc`, we must call `[super dealloc]` last, instead of first?

I ask because I don't understand why, if I put `[super dealloc]` first, and release an object using `[_bar release]` on the next line,  I don't get a segmentation fault. After `[super dealloc]` runs, if it frees the object's memory, `_bar` should already be a memory chunk that doesn't belong to the process.

Comment: Please rephrase your question. I have read it twice and I do not understand what you are asking.

Comment: Objective-C is using C function for getting memory and freeing memory, right?  So it uses `malloc` and `free`.  The question is, where are the places that is done in Objective-C?

Comment: Are you asking where the Objective-C runtime does it (implementation detail, we don't know/care) or where you as a developer are supposed to use malloc/free? (If you use active voice instead of passive voice, your writing will be clearer.)

Comment: I think in general, we won't use malloc or free in Objective-C, so what I am asking is, we know Objective-C does allocate memory and free up memory, because it is based on C, so where and how does it happen.  We can say it is an implementation details of Objective-C, but it should be some what clear of about where it is, and I am thinking that it should be the very base class's `-dealloc`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are saying, you have this code:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
    [_bar release]; // _bar is a member variable
}
```

And you expect to get a segmentation fault on the second line, but in practice you are not.

The reason for this is luck!

The OS will trap access to memory that your process does not own, but it doesn't police everything that happens inside your process. In this case, you are accessing memory that you have marked as free, but it still belongs to your process, and so behavior is *undefined*. The memory was valid a few milliseconds ago, and so it is likely that nobody has started reusing this page of memory yet, and so it probably still has valid data on it. So it might succeed. But it also might fail.

This is bad code and you shouldn't ship it. But just because it is incorrect and undefined doesn't mean it won't work.

Comment: Turn on MallocScribble in the scheme editor in Xcode.  The above code will crash every time exactly because the memory will be explicitly trashed on free().

Comment: so if you don't turn it on, it may not crash?  I was thinking earlier that, maybe it is freed, but also freed by some kind of lower level autorelease pool mechanism, so that's why it may exist until the event loop is done for the current iteration

Comment: @JeremyL as I commented already, in C (and C++ and Objective C) accessing memory you have already freed does not segfault. You can, in general, access any address that is physically mapped to (virtual) memory. However there's no guarantee that the data has not changed. You are in the realm of undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

`-dealloc` ultimately frees the memory associated with an Objective-C object (presumably through `free()`, but that's an implementation detail.) The only reason you are able to send a message after `-dealloc` is because of undefined behaviour. After `[super dealloc]` is sent, any further messages to `self` or its ivars is unsafe.

Answer (score 1):

In the simplest "conceptual" case, the `dealloc` routine for NSObject does the `free` operation, mirroring the `malloc` done in the `alloc` routine.  In practice it may be different, but that's all smoke and mirrors, so long as the conceptual model is satisfied.

If you put `[super dealloc]` first in your (pre-ARC) `dealloc` routine it mostly doesn't seg fault because the space, while freed, has not had time to be overwritten by some other object (and it doesn't physically go away when deallocated -- it just goes into an "available" list).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `alloc` is where the allocation is done. Note that it may or may not be done, sometimes there's no allocation at all (this is an implementation detail). The allocation generally happens in the `NSObject` implementation of `alloc`.

**If** memory was allocated, then the chained call to `dealloc` is the one that eventually releases it.

You are not supposed to access instance variables after calling `[super dealloc]`. This does not mean that if you do you get a segfault. You may or may not segfault, it's undefined behavior.

An important thing to remember, however, is that you should **never** call `dealloc` directly, except for the call to `[super dealloc]` in the dealloc implementation itself. Objective C is reference counted. When you are done with an object you do not `dealloc` it. Instead you `release` it (or `autorelease` it if you are done but you are returning it to the caller and have no idea if the caller will use it or not). The actual call to `dealloc` happens automatically when the system is sure that nobody is going to reference that object any more.

Edit:

I shall clarify *sometimes there's no allocation at all*. In fact the allocation generally happen if you call alloc, but the init* methods may undo it. As a rule all calls to `alloc` should immediately be followed by a call to one of the initializers. The initializers, however, do not need to initialize the `self` they receive. They could instead get rid of it (therefore freeing the memory) and return a completely different object, which may or may not be allocated.

Therefore, in that case, the memory allocated by `alloc` is in fact released by the initializer (may or may not call `dealloc` to do that). ANd the object that you get after initialization may be a static object that is not allocated on the heap and will never be freed. It could also be a non pointer (an invalid address) that is cast to `(void*)` (aka `id`) and returned.

Comment: right, i understand that the framework or Foundation calls it, when the retain count is 0, by the release method (or when the autorelease pool drains and release all objects it contains)

Comment: Well. As per the title of your question, the answer is: you should not. It's undefined behavior. And as all undefined behavior it may or may not work. And it may work today, then not work tomorrow even if you are running the same binary.

Comment: The related question in the OP is "where is `free` called". You should not worry about it. Anyway it's mostly in the NSObject implementation of `dealloc` and it may or may not happen in some initializers (this is again undocumented internal details).

Comment: «the memory allocated by alloc is in fact released by the initializer (may or may not call dealloc to do that)» The correct way for an initializer to free the instance it's passed is to simply send `release`, which will proceed as usual to `dealloc`.

Comment: Yes. But that's the correct way for **you** to do it. There's no guarantee that this is what **Apple** does internally. Especially because some classes are in fact toll free bridged and at a lower level there's no calling `release` as there's no object at all. It may be a call to `CFRelease` instead. And even that may or may not be the case for code implemented by Apple itself.